# Display more statistics on CV views

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I am suggesting that extra statistics be added on who is viewing your CV, something akin to the geo location of the public search.

It would be good to know which regions are viewing your CV.

Answer (score 1):

Yes please! In fact, would it kill you to tell us the logged-in user/employer names that viewed the CV?

It's not like an individual careers user having access to this information would be detrimental to the SO/SE/FogCreek bottom line, is it?

On the other hand, it would give those of us who have spent money on hosting our CV with SO, some idea of what we got for our money, right?

Comment: But it probably would be detrimental to the employers that viewed your CV as you could contact them when they obviously weren't interested enough to contact you, yet.

Comment: @C. Ross it's not because one employee from this company is not interested, that another departement or Employee is not interested in your C.V.